# count with multiple crieria

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, countif

I am stuck with a problem. Lets say I have the following data in range A1:K4

```
row1    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
row2    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
row3    3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
row4    3   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
```

And the following data in range N1:P4

```
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   5
11  12  13
```

I want formulas in range R1:R4

The desired output should be R1=1, R2=2, R3=3, R4=1

i am trying to evaluate first set of numbers 1 2 and 3 and check in every row from row1 to row4 and find out how many rows matched all 3 numbers and the put the value in cell R1.. continue this for all 4 sets of number. Can someone help me with a formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this formula in R1 copied down to R4

`=SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B$1:K$4,ROW(B$1:K$4)-ROW(B$1),0,1),N1:P1),{1;1;1})=3)+0)`

although I've cheated a bit, there, because `{1;1;1}` is variable based on the number of columns in `N1:P1` (and so is the `3`), so for a more generic version (which would allow `N1:P1` to be any size row) you can use this "array formula"

`=SUM((MMULT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B$1:K$4,ROW(B$1:K$4)-ROW(B$1),0,1),N1:P1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(N1:P1)^0))=COLUMNS(N1:P1))+0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am definitely going to find a bit difficult to understand how it works. I tried the array version and it did work but when I deleted the values in column P, all values in column R turned zero. Instead of triplets, I was just trying to figure out if the same formula works for doubles or for quadraples but it didnt work.

Comment: If you only want to use N1:O1 then you need to change all references from N1:P1 to N1:O1.....or if you want to allow blanks in the N1:P1 range then change final COLUMNS function to COUNT, i.e. `=SUM((MMULT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B$1:K$4,ROW(B$1:K$4)-ROW(B$1),0,1),N1:P1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(N1:P1)^0))=COUNT(N1:P1))+0)`